# CKEditor : Switching to Source View via Javascript

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I need a way to make my CKEditor either load in the 'Source' view via a config option or be able to set it to the 'Source' view via a javascript method.

By default the CKEditor loads into the WYSIWYG view, but I need to display the HTML by default.

I've searched through the archives here as well as the developer's documentation over at CKEditor, but I fail to find my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is [config.startupMode](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-startupMode)

> The mode to load at the editor startup. It depends on the plugins
>   loaded. By default, the wysiwyg and source modes are available.

```
config.startupMode = 'source';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for instance ready and fire off the command for source mode

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');    
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(event) {
    event.editor.commands.source.exec();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wa81Lrny/1/

Comment: You should use `editor.execCommand( 'source' )` instead of calling the command's exec callback. The former checks the command state and fires some events.